# Linking a guest account to a real account

Tags: support

I have just answered a question on the Puzzling page and got it right. I used a guest account because at the time I didnt have an account to write with and wanted to be first (of course). Is there anyway to link that answer to my new account because I dont get the credit for the answer on my account?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the 'contact us' link at the bottom of the page, and explain what the problem is.

Comment: Thanks, I have done that now.